# ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer is reducing concurrency count while partition exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have a spring boot application for produce messages to kafka. This application is running under high traffic for 10million request per day on 6 instance. I have a spring boot kafka consumer app also. But this application have 2 instance and these instances could not consuming all messages because this application is running single thread. My topics have 4 partition and i want to do consumer app multithread according to partition count. But i am not sure is my code working.

Spring Kafka maven dependeny

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Configuration Class

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaListenerConfig {

    private final KafkaListenerProperties kafkaListenerProperties;

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =  new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(4);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(kafkaConsumerProps());
    }
    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> kafkaConsumerProps() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaListenerProperties.getBootstrap());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaListenerProperties.getGroup());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "100");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "15000");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return props;
    }

}
```

According to partition count of my topic i setted concurrency field to 4

```
factory.setConcurrency(4);
```

Topic Partitions:

```
        Topic:fraudSSCALogs     PartitionCount:4        ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:
        Topic: fraudSSCALogs    Partition: 0    Leader: 62      Replicas: 62    Isr: 62
        Topic: fraudSSCALogs    Partition: 1    Leader: 166     Replicas: 166   Isr: 166
        Topic: fraudSSCALogs    Partition: 2    Leader: 270     Replicas: 270   Isr: 270
        Topic: fraudSSCALogs    Partition: 3    Leader: 167     Replicas: 167   Isr: 167
```

Listener Class

```
public class SSCAReqResLogListener {

@KafkaListener(id= "consumer0",topicPartitions = {@TopicPartition(topic="${kafka.consumer.topic}", partitions = {"0"})})
public void receive1(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
    proceed(record);
}

@KafkaListener(id= "consumer1",topicPartitions = {@TopicPartition(topic="${kafka.consumer.topic}", partitions = {"1"})})
public void receive2(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
    proceed(record);
}

@KafkaListener(id= "consumer2",topicPartitions = {@TopicPartition(topic="${kafka.consumer.topic}", partitions = {"2"})})
public void receive3(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
    proceed(record);
}

@KafkaListener(id= "consumer3",topicPartitions = {@TopicPartition(topic="${kafka.consumer.topic}", partitions = {"3"})})
public void receive4(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
    proceed(record);
}

private synchronized void proceed(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
    log.info("Message Received: Topic: {}, Partition: {}, Value: {}", record.topic(), record.partition(), record.value());
}

}
```

When my application running up spring alert a warning;

```
WARN  [main] org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer: When specific partitions are provided, the concurrency must be less than or equal to the number of partitions; reduced from 4 to 1
```

What is the problem of my configuration? What can i do for fix this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have explicitly defined partitions, the `concurrency` can only be set to a number less than or equal to the number of partitions.

You have only defined one partition for each topic, so the concurrency can only be set to `1`. The code sanity checks this and automatically drops the concurrency level and gives you a warning.

```
@KafkaListener(id= "consumer0",topicPartitions = {@TopicPartition(
    topic="${kafka.consumer.topic}",
    partitions = {"0"}   // <-- Only one partition
)})
```

Multiple partitions would be configured something like this:

```
@KafkaListener(id= "consumer0",topicPartitions = {@TopicPartition(
    topic="${kafka.consumer.topic}",
    partitions = {"0", "1", "2", "3" }
)})
```

Comment: This solution solved my problem. But is it really running parallel cause just one thread running with id consumer0?

Comment: It should be running multiple threads. The thread names will be similar. What tool have you used to count the number of threads?